# How to remove past data from your search results and only display the current one

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

Here is the code I wrote in the $sql variable in my includes file:

```
SELECT 
  itemName, itemRate, itemStatus, itemTrend 
FROM 
  items 
WHERE 
  itemName LIKE '%$search%' 
ORDER BY 
  rowID DESC
```

and here is what the results look like:

[image]

I get both past data and current data. I only need to display the current data. Thanks if you can help!

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Sample data and expected results would be helpful.  Do you have a `datetime` field you want to filter by?  You can use something like `getdate()` to filter it against -- `where yourfield <= getdate()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by past data and current data? Is there a date column so we can say it's new data?

If you want to get the last item only, then this will do the trick:

```
SELECT itemName, itemRate, itemStatus, itemTrend FROM items WHERE itemName LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY rowID DESC LIMIT 1
```

---

```
SELECT itemName, itemRate, itemStatus, itemTrend FROM items WHERE itemName LIKE '%$search%' GROUP BY itemName ORDER BY rowID DESC
```

Comment: Yes I did that however it only shows 1 result... Like if I have 2 items that start with Phoenix... (ex. Phoenix Wings and Phoenix Pacifier) It will only display one of those...